# What is wrong with this mongoose aggregation?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, momentjs

I'm trying to query my mongodb collection using a `moment` object. The documents contain a date field that looks like this:

```
  "date" : ISODate("2019-03-21T00:00:00Z"),
```

A normal query like this works fine:

```
  const now = moment().utc()
  console.log(await Price.find({ date: now.startOf('day') }))
```

However when I try this:

```
  const results = await Price.aggregate([
    { $match: { date: now.startOf('day') } }
  ])
```

I get no results. Why is this happening?

I get results in the aggregation if the query is `{ date: new Date(now.startOf('day')) }` which is a little strange.

Comment: According to the mongo docs, "The [$match] query syntax is identical to the read operation query syntax," which suggests that the error is somewhere in how mongoose is converting those moment date-like objects into dates for its actual queries. If you enable mongoose debug mode, you should hopefully be able to see the final queries that it's sending to mongo and compare them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that Mongoose will cast query values according to the model's defined schema for `find`, but not for `aggregate`.

This is noted in the docs [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#aggregate_Aggregate):

> Mongoose does **not** cast pipeline stages.

Which explains why using `{ date: new Date(now.startOf('day')) }` works, as that's exactly the sort of manual casting you have to do with `aggregate`.